# Font to polygon or triangle mesh

Tags: 3d-meshes, fonts

I've been happy using bitmap fonts for games so far, but now I find I really need the polygon edge in some form. I saw the freetype engine some time ago, which can provide rastering of truetype fonts from within your engine, but what I think I really want for my current project is some way of converting from truetype to a triangle mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I think you want FTGL](http://homepages.paradise.net.nz/henryj/code/), which can convert font outlines to meshes and extruded meshes, among other formats. I don't know if it only generates triangle meshes; you might need to run a triangulation algorithm on the output.

Comment: although the source looks hard to use and there is little documentation as far as I can tell, this certainly does answer the question.

Comment: The link is now dead.